# How plot sub columns in R

Tags: r

I have this code for the dataset UCBAdmissions and I want to plot how many male students and how many female students were admitted to department A but I don't know how to do it.

```
admit.rows <- as.data.frame(lapply(as.data.frame.table(UCBAdmissions), function(x)rep(x, as.data.frame.table(UCBAdmissions)$Freq)))[, -4]
plot(admit.rows$Gender,admit.rows$Dept)
plot(admit.rows$Gender, admit.rows$Dept)
```

Should I take only the data for department A and then try to plot it based on gender or is it possible using the whole dataset?

Answer (score 3):

I'd show a mosaic plot with shading for that dataset.

```
library(vcd)

mosaic(~Gender+Admit+Dept, data=UCBAdmissions, split_vertical=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), shade=TRUE)
```

---

[image]

The residual shadings are shown at the right of the figure and are cut into five categories. Those cells having residuals ≥ 2 and ≥ 4, equating to p-values of <0.05 and <0.001, respectively, are shaded in light and dark blue, while cells having correspondingly large negative residuals are shaded in light and dark red. The graph indicates that males are more likely than females to be admitted to departments A and B. There are other notable differences, but the overall impression is that there is a large amount of imbalance in the data, which is a warning that confounding may exist.

Comment: The confounding effect in the data is that females in this data set were more likely to apply to departments that had higher rejection rates. For details, see the help for [UCBAdmissions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/datasets/versions/3.6.2/topics/UCBAdmissions).

Answer (score 1):

The plot from the [UCBAdmissions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/datasets/versions/3.6.2/topics/UCBAdmissions) help file illustrates that females were more likely to apply to departments with higher rejection rates (departments C, D, E, and F).

Posting as Community wiki since this plot is from the help documentation, and is not an "original" answer.

```
require(graphics)
## Data aggregated over departments
apply(UCBAdmissions, c(1, 2), sum)
mosaicplot(apply(UCBAdmissions, c(1, 2), sum),
           main = "Student admissions at UC Berkeley")
## Data for individual departments
opar <- par(mfrow = c(2, 3), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0))
for(i in 1:6)
     mosaicplot(UCBAdmissions[,,i],
                xlab = "Admit", ylab = "Sex",
                main = paste("Department", LETTERS[i]))
mtext(expression(bold("Student admissions at UC Berkeley")),
      outer = TRUE, cex = 1.5)
par(opar)
```

The first plot, aggregated over departments, shows that more males were admitted than females.

[image]

The second plot, a matrix of 2x2 charts by department, makes visible the confounding effect of differential acceptance rates by department.

[image]